# 3-pin SMD Marking VB Part Identification

Tags: transistors, identification, open-collector

I can't determine the part number for this open collector.

[image: open collector drivers]

[image: vbz]

[image: vbn]

Answer (score 2):

The part is a SOT23 NPN Transistor, specifically [NSS40201LT1G](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nss40201l-d.pdf) by On Semiconductor.

From the datasheet, we have the part marking code information:

[image: Marking Description from Datasheet]

The transistor shown in the image matches this, with the `VB` device code, followed by a single character data code `Z`. As noted the date code can be in any orientation and on-semi parts seem to frequently have this character rotated 90 degrees. There is also the Pb-Free microdot marking in the lower centre location as indicated.

The pinout also matches the expected for this device (TBH a lot of other SOT23 NPNs share the same pinout). With the base, being pin 1 (bottom right on marking diagram), going to a thin trace with series resistor as would be expected, and the two remaining pins going to nice wide current carrying traces.

[image: Transistor pinout]